# Error in React Native Parallax View

Tags: react-native

I'm using the library [react-native-parallax-view](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-parallax-view) and I keep on getting this error. Even the example doesn't work. What is causing this?

**2015-11-30 14:26:59.836 [error][tid:main] Unable to resolve module Dimensions from /Users/hiran/research/react-native/myapp/node_modules/react-native-parallax-view/lib/ParallaxView.js: Invalid directory /Users/node_modules/Dimensions**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. In your project directory node_modules/react-native-parallax-view/lib/ you will find the ParallaxView.js file. Update the lines as follows.

```
var screen = require('Dimensions').get('window');
```

Replace this with

```
var screen = Dimensions.get('window');
```

and add **Dimensions** to the import list as,

```
var {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    Animated,
    Dimensions,
    } = React;
```

Hope the author would update this soon.